# How to reply the last whisper (MP) in chat

Tags: wakfu

There is any way to reply the last private message (whisper) you received directly in chat? I like to always use the main chat window (no separate tabs for private chats) and I guess if there is some method, like `/r` or something like this, to answer to the last whisper.

I can remember there was something like this in the beta, but now I can't find how. Currently I have to put the complete command which include the name of the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this wiki article](http://wakfu.wikia.com/wiki/Commands_and_Shortcuts) it seems that what you ought to try is `Ctrl+up`. You could also bind a numpad key to /w whoever. Can you not click the names of people in chat to automatically start typing a message to them?

Comment: I don't mantain conversations always with the same person. I already have shorcuts for the person I talk more. Later I will try the `Ctrl+up` method

Comment: Yes, to the clicking method, but when writing I'm not using the mouse. it's pretty annoying to get the mouse to every message

Comment: I do not play the game so all I am going by is my experience in MMOs and that article. Not really sure about the ctrl+up thing because it says "Contact". That could mean a person in your contact list or the last person you contacted. You'll find out, I suppose.